# Rician distribution from k-factor

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Is the value of the k-factor sufficient to produce a Rician distributed random variable?
The authors in [1],[2] and some other papers have defined a Rician distributed random variable as
\begin{align}
X\sim CN(\sqrt{(\dfrac{k}{k+1})},\dfrac{1}{1+k}),----------(1)
\end{align}
where $CN$ denotes the complex-Normal distribution. While in majority of the literature the PDF of Rician fading is defined as:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{2x}{\alpha}\text{exp}\left(\frac{-(x^2+v^2)}{\alpha}\right)I_0\left(\frac{2xv}{\alpha}\right),--------------(2)$$

where $I_0(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind with order zero.

I know that the second approach is correct. But I am confused if the first method is correct too. Obviously, if the first method (1) is accurate it would provide a much easier way to produce Rician distributed random variables. Further, some of the authors that use the first approach are actually highly respected researchers in their fields (I know that this does not mean that they can not be wrong).

The Wikipedia article on Rician distribution also states that Rician distribution can be approximated as $R=\sqrt{(X^2+Y^2)}$ where $X\sim N(v Cos\theta,\sigma^2)$ and $Y\sim N(v Sin\theta,\sigma^2)$. But this is also not the same thing as (1) because we need the values of $v$ and $\sigma$, whereas, in (1) we only need that value of the k-factor.

Is (1) correct? If so, why? Is the proof available somewhere? Will the random variable in (1) follow the distribution in (2)?

[1] D. W. K. Ng and R. Schober, "Dynamic Resource Allocation in OFDMA Systems with Full-Duplex and Hybrid Relaying," 2011 IEEE International Conference on Communications (ICC), 2011, pp. 1-6, doi: 10.1109/icc.2011.5962906

[2] D. W. K. Ng and R. Schober, "Cross-Layer Scheduling for OFDMA Amplify-and-Forward Relay Networks," 2009 IEEE 70th Vehicular Technology Conference Fall, 2009, pp. 1-5, doi: 10.1109/VETECF.2009.5378812.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a complex RV, where $X=X_r+jX_i$, $X_r\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma^2)$ and $X_i\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma^2)$,
with real and imaginary parts being IID, its modulus follows Rician distribution with parameter $v^2=\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2$ and $\alpha=\sigma^2$.

In Rician fading channel, the envelope of random perturbation on recieved signal follows Rician distribution. And the random amplitude and phase perturbation can be modeled as complex Gaussian random variable.

As for your question, (1) is complex Guassian distribution and (2) is the true Rician distribution. And you can find proof in http://ece-research.unm.edu/bsanthan/ece541/note2.pdf.